# Get next tag name with position in XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, if-statement

I want to check if the next parent is `test` or `foo` using `position(.)+1` (that's the idea).

XML:

```
<text>
   <list>
      in list
   </list>
   <table>
      I'M HERE
   </table>
</text>
<foo>
   <hey>
   </hey>
</foo>
```

Can I do something like that ?

XSL :

```
<xsl:if test="position(.)+1 = 'foo'">
  <xsl:value-of select="'Next tag is foo'" />
</xsl:if>
```

And I want to know if I can put 2 conditions in `<xsl:if>` like :

My output is in html.

Edit : wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed your question significantly. First you wanted the first child, now the following sibling, will answer both cases, first the explanation of the above terms:

```
<text>
  <table></table>    <-- first child       (nested one level)
</text>
<foo />              <-- following sibling (same hierarchy level)
```

**Check if the first *child* of `<text>` is `<list>` or `<table>`**

The query you are looking for is:

```
<xsl:if test="name(*[1]) = 'list' or name(*[1]) = 'table'">
```

Full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/text">
        <xsl:if test="name(*[1]) = 'list' or name(*[1]) = 'table'">
            <xsl:text>first child of text node is list or table</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Check if the following sibling of `<text>` is `<list>` or `<table>`**

The query you are looking for is:

```
<xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'list' or name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'table'">
```

Full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/text">
        <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'list' or name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'table'">
            <xsl:text>following sibling of text node is list or table</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost.

1. Use the `following-sibling` axis to get the next element (`following-sibling::*[1]`) <sup>[*]</sup>
2. Use the `self` axis to check if that element itself is a `<list>` (`[self::list]`)

e.g. <sup>[+]</sup>

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::list]">
  <xsl:value-of select="'Next tag is list'" />
</xsl:if>
```

---

<sup>[*]</sup> `following-sibling::*` selects *all* following siblings, you want only the first one, hence the `[1]`.

<sup>[+]</sup> Multiple predicates (sub-expressions in square brackets) must be true *in succession*. This means the XPath expression either selects a non-empty node set (which evaluates to `true` in a Boolean test) or it selects the empty node-set (which evaluates to `false`). There is no need for an explicit comparison here.

Comment: My answer assumes that your context node is `<text>` and you want to find out whether the immediately following element is `<list>` (or `<foo>`, or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for all your help and for a good alternative to using `name()`!

Comment: Using `name()` is in fact the slightly inferior variant. An actual node test via the `self::` axis is preferable, especially when XML namespaces come into play, but both approaches will work for this simple case.